# Vue composition API watch object

Tags: vue.js

How to watch object, and get previous and new value? Code below, after call changeName(), I got same n and o.

And can someone explain what is "flush" do? I can't find good document online.

```js
setup(){
        const users=ref([{ name: 'John' }]);
        const changeName=(name)=>{ users.value[0].name='Alex'; };
        watch(
           ()=>users.value,
           (n,o)=>{ console.log(n,o); },
                {
                    lazy: false,
                    deep: true,
                    flush: 'post'  // pre,post,sync
                }
            );
        return {users, changeName};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you really want to do with it. But to actually get it to fire the watch you could do:

```js
watch(
  () => user.value.map(u => u.name),
  (n, o) => console.log(n,o),
)
```